# Metamask contract amount in ether is showing 0 instead of user input in the formData

Tags: javascript, solidity

In this example (Refer to screenshot error), user wants to transfer 0.002 ether to the target address. However when the server connects to metamask, the transaction amount shown in metamask is 0 instead of 0.002.

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQtUU.jpg)

I have a Input form for user to input the amount of ether they want to transfer to an address. This user input data amount is passed to the TransactionContext.jsx file (see code below) and into the sendTransaction function. I console.log the parseAmount that was passed to sendTransaction function and it is correctly showing as 0.002 ether. Hence, I am not sure why metamask is showing 0 ether.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ethers} from 'ethers'
import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants"
export const TransactionContext = React.createContext()

const { ethereum } = window;

const createEthereumContract = async () => {
  
try {
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);
  
    return transactionContract;
} catch (error) {console.error('Error creating Ethereum contract:', error);
  
}
};

//function to check if a wallet is connected at the start
export const TransactionProvider = ({children}) => {
  
  const [formData, setformData] = useState({ addressTo: "", amount: "", keyword: "", message: "" });
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("transactionCount"));
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);
  
  //handleChange func interact with inputs except the event
  const handleChange = (e, name) => {
    setformData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  const getAllTransactions = async () =>{
    //check if browser has metamask installed
    try {if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")

    const transactionContract = await createEthereumContract();
    const availableTransactions = await transactionContract.getAllTransactions();
    
    //change structure of data 
    const structuredTransactions = availableTransactions.map((transaction)=>({
      addressTo: transaction.receiver,
      addressFrom: transaction.sender,
      timestamp: new Date(Number(transaction.timestamp) * 1000).toLocaleString(),
      message: transaction.message,
      keyword: transaction.keyword,
      amount: parseInt(transaction.amount._hex) / (10 ** 18)
    }))

    console.log(structuredTransactions)

    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);

    }
  }


  const checkIfWalletIsConnected = async() =>{
    try{
      if(!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamask")
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({method:'eth_accounts'})
      console.log(accounts)

      if(accounts.length){
        setCurrentAccount(accounts[0])

        getAllTransactions()

      } else {
        console.log('No accounts found')
      }
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error("No ethereum object")
    }
  }

const checkIfTransactionsExist = async () => {
  try {
    const transactionContract = await createEthereumContract()
    const transactionCount = await transactionContract.getTransactionCount()

    window.localStorage.setItem("transactionCount",transactionCount)

  } catch(error) {

  }

}

  {/*function for connecting the account */}
  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install MetaMask.");

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts", });

      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  }

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
        const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
        const transactionContract = await createEthereumContract();
        const parsedAmount = ethers.parseEther(amount);

        console.log(parsedAmount)

        await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_sendTransaction",
          params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          }],
        });

        const transactionHash = await transactionContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);

        setIsLoading(true);
        console.log(`Loading - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        await transactionHash.wait();
        console.log(`Success - ${transactionHash.hash}`);
        setIsLoading(false);

        const transactionCount = await transactionContract.getTransactionCount();

        setTransactionCount(Number(transactionCount));
        window.location.reload();
        
      } else {
        console.log("No ethereum object");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);

      throw new Error("No ethereum object");
    }
  }


  {/* need a use effect function to call check if wallet is connected right inside */}
  useEffect(()=>{
    checkIfWalletIsConnected()
    checkIfTransactionsExist()
  },[])


  
  return(
<TransactionContext.Provider value={{connectWallet, currentAccount,formData,handleChange,sendTransaction,transactions,isLoading}}>
  {children} 
  
  {/*whatever we wrap inside of this transaction provider is going to be rented and 
  its going to have access to this value object*/}

</TransactionContext.Provider>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install web3

```
npm i web3
```

Then import it in project file

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

and use this to pass in your value

```
value: parseInt(Web3.utils.toWei(amount,"ether")).toString(16),
```

Comment: Please explain why this helps to solve the problem described at the top of this page.

Comment: It helps convert the amount inputted amount into wei and the to hex. This is the format that is understood by the smart contract.

Comment: Please edit the explanation into the answer.